# Right way to kill google chrome processes in automation anywhere

Tags: automationanywhere

What will be the right way to kill all the chrome processes in automation anywhere.

I have tried writing a vb script to kill chrome which works fine, but wanted to know if there are any other better options available in the tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option available is to use the **Run Program/File command**

Under ProgramFile/Path give `TASKKill`

Under Parameters give `/f /im chrome.exe`